# QTcpSocket descriptor error

Tags: qt, tcpserver

I was trying to learn some about TCP server and sockets and stuck at this situation. I am creating server and connect sockets to it. But I cant get right descriptor for these sockets. However when I check nextPendingConnection, it has correct descriptor.

Here is a simple code:

```
QTcpServer server;
server.listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2500);

QObject::connect(&server, &QTcpServer::newConnection, [&] {
    qDebug()<<"New connection recieved!";
    QTcpSocket* connection = server.nextPendingConnection();
    qDebug()<<"socket descriptor: "<<connection->socketDescriptor();  // here i have some correct descriptor
    connection->waitForReadyRead();
});

QTcpSocket *s = new QTcpSocket;
qDebug()<<s->socketDescriptor();  // here i get -1
s->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2500);
qDebug()<<s->socketDescriptor();  // and here i get -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the -1 because the socket is not connected yet. Add this after you declare QTcpSocket *s = new QTcpSocket;, and you will see a valid descriptor:

```
QObject::connect(s, &QTcpSocket::connected, [&] {
    qDebug()<<"socket descriptor (c): "<<s->socketDescriptor();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Rolf, I tried like you've said. But the signal is not even emitted.

```
    QTcpSocket *s = new QTcpSocket;

    QObject::connect(s, &QTcpSocket::connected, [&] {
        qDebug()<<" --- socket descriptor (c): "<<s->socketDescriptor();
    });

    s->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2500);
```

However, I get the slot from the server on new connection... strange

Also, I've added:

```
    QObject::connect(s, &QTcpSocket::stateChanged, [&] {
        qDebug()<<" --- socket state (c): "<<s->state();
    });
```

and state is first HostLookupState and then ConnectingState but never ConnectedState –

p.s. sorry for answering from another account. Mixed them not on purpose

Comment: Strange, tested quickly (on MacOS) and it worked for me:

    socket descriptor:  3
    socket descriptor (c):  21

You could check with Wireshark if the 3-way handshake goes through and some system tool (depending on your OS) what the OS believes the socket state is.

Comment: Hey, Rolf
I've got new situation after adding "waitForConnected". Here is the code:
        s->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2500);
        if(!s->waitForConnected(5000))
        {
            qDebug() << "Error: " << s->errorString();
        }
So, I'm recieving descriptors from sockets methods but they are different from what tcp server is giving me. Do you have ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see this before since I did not use it in my earlier trial. You should not use waitForReadyRead and such. They are blocking calls! You really need to use signals and slots and connect to the ready read signal. This should fix it I think.